Custom chakra UI stepper steps not evenly spaced

That is what it currently looks like, I want the steps to be evenly spaced. Using flexbox seems not to apply changes for some reason. Documentation & AI hasn't helped either.
Theme file in question:
export const stepperTheme = defineStyleConfig({
  baseStyle: {
    step: {
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      alignItems: "center",
      position: "relative",
    },

    separator: {
      position: "absolute",
      top: "20px",
      left: "50%",
      height: "2px",
      bgColor: "grey.600",
      zIndex: "-1",
    },

    indicator: {
      zIndex: "1",
      width: "40px",
      height: "40px",

      "&[data-status=complete]": {
        bgColor: "cyan.600",
        borderColor: "cyan.600",
        borderWidth: "3px",
      },

      "&[data-status=active]": {
        bgColor: "cyan.600",
        borderColor: "cyan.600",
        outline: "2.5px solid white",
        outlineOffset: "-4px",
      },

      "&[data-status=incomplete]": {
        bgColor: "white",
        borderColor: "grey.600",
        borderWidth: "2px",
      },
    },
  },
});

